# Is a productcode always numeric?

Tags: data-modeling

I have a table called `products`, and I want to use the `productcode` as  a `unique primary key` and I am wondering if it should be A `VARCHAR` or an `INT`  datatype?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457136/number-or-char-for-primary-key-column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445649/is-it-ok-to-use-character-values-for-primary-keys , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925266/database-design-and-the-use-of-non-numeric-primary-keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number or char for primary key column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457136/number-or-char-for-primary-key-column)